# Tab Route Change

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I have angular tab

```
<tab (select)="goTo('materials')" id="materials"></tab>
```

component `goTo(url) {
    this._router.navigate([url], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }`

in another tab "general" i have a link redirect to this "material" tab but when i click it it redirect to the right link and load the corresponding view but the tab name "general" hasn't  changed

```
<i (click)="goto('../general')"></i>
```

component : `goto(tabname){
      this.router.navigate([tabname], { relativeTo: this.route });
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Event emitter to connect the two component to trigger (select) method in the parent component